# Empty as a container for a object

Tags: effects

Can an "empty cube" be used to hold liquid? I have found nothing on YOUTUBE nor any other help sites.

What I would like to do is use an empty to replace actual text, and have liquid going in it to make the shape of the text. If that makes sense.

Comment: I made a render of actual mesh text with a fluid modifier. Empties can not be used to hold liquid. Something you could try is adding a transparent cube.

Comment: Thank you. The second question is can the cube be made an object of the text? as the liquid fills the cube the text will become visible.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the text to be a diffuse material once seen, is that right?

Comment: Have you tried using a cube and then switching it visibility to camera off?

Comment: yes, after messing the empty for way too long.